# JWT client server connection not found

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, jwt

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbpK0.png)

**Server Site**

Getting Email query from server site, It's not connecting to my client site But it's working on my server site

```js
app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.body;
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: '1d'
    });
    res.send({ accessToken });
});
```

**Client Ste Login Function Part**

This is my client site login part functional and callback part, There my email is showing in console but doesn't work in server which I show in picture.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { useAuthState, useSignInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import GoogleButton from 'react-google-button';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from '../Firebase.init';

const Login = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [signInWithEmailAndPassword, loading, error] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
    if (user) {
        navigate('/');
    }

    const handleLogin = async e => {
        alert('ok');

        e.preventDefault();
        const email = e.target.email.value;
        const password = e.target.password.value;
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', { email })
        console.log(data);
        console.log(email);
    };
}
```

Comment: `app.get` services a **GET** request - you're sending a **POST** request